# Kohana query builder return

Tags: php, orm, kohana, query-builder, kohana-orm

We have a CMS written in Kohana 2.3.x (yes, we know it is an old one).
When I use the query builder like this:

```
$obj = ORM::factory('product')->where(array_of_wheres)->find_all()
```

than the `$obj` will be an `ORM_Iterator`.

But when I write something like this:

```
$obj = ORM::factory('product');
if($something)
    $obj->where(array_of_wheres);
else
    $obj->where(array_of_other_wheres);
$obj->find_all();
```

Than the `$obj` will be a `Product_Model` instead of `ORM_Iterator`.

Can someone explain why is this happening?

Thanks, Dave.

Comment: Are you using PHP 5.6.21 or PHP 7.0.5 ?

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.5.12

Comment: what is type of $return = $obj->find_all(); it must be DB result or some kind of Iterator

Comment: In2nd code $obj is Actual ORM object for Product Model not result of find_all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first example `$obj` is result of `find_all()` function that is a `ORM_Iterator` called by on anonymous object of Product Model.

But in 2nd example `$obj` is ORM object for Product Model. When you call find_all function it returns result as ORM_Iterator it does not modify original object.

Here is correct way to do it

```
$model = ORM::factory('product');
if($something)
    $model->where(array_of_wheres);
else
    $model->where(array_of_other_wheres);
$obj = $model->find_all();
```

Comment: Oh, what a shame I didn't realized this little mistake... Thanks a lot!